# AS3 gallery imitating iphone swipe gesture?

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to create an image gallery where the main image is centered, when you click down on it and "swipe" it to the left or right, the next/prev image will be center.

It should kind of imitate the feel of the iphone page swipe motion.

Here is [an image link](http://img862.imageshack.us/img862/318/swipe.jpg).

Does anyone know any good tutorials or how I can get started with AS3?

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't exactly the same, it will give you a fantastic starting point

http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/effects/iphone-page-transition-flash/

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to create could be called "touch (kinetic) scrolling with a snapping". Take a look at Scroller class source from Flex 4.5 SDK (Hero) and make it better. You will need to spend time on it to make it work good enough. If you're doing this for a mouse-based input — just forget about it since this is a good idea for touch-based input only.

Comment: Yeah I just need it to work with a mouse, but I will still take a look. thanks for that buddy.